# MySQL instances are pointing to the database server DNS causing slow connection

Tags: mysql

We have very slow connection when accessing MySQL instances but fast when using IP address. When checked, we found out that the instances are all registered to the server hostname. So when you do an nslookup to the instance hostname, it will not show an address. I am not a database person, do you think there is something missing on the mysql setup? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with name resolution. I would start making sure that hostname of the MySQL server can be resolved and that the reverse DNS (IN PTR) of the clients is resolved too.

Best solution is to fix the DNS.

If you do not have access to DNS, you can edit the hosts file on both client and server and make sure that the client can resolve the server hostname and that the server can resolve the IP of the client.

If you can not fix the DNS for the clients, and you are using IP for MySQL usernames, you can disable reverse DNS resolution that MySQL performs for each authentication with `skip_name_resolve` option.

See also:

- [skip_name_resolve](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_skip_name_resolve) documentation
- [5.1.12.3 DNS Lookups and the Host Cache](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/host-cache.html) chapter from MySQL manual

Comment: Thank you for your comment Mircea. Will try this.

Comment: Hello again... the problem is that all the instance IPs are pointing to a single DNS entry, which is the database server. I want to check if the instance IP and hostname in the MySQL are set up properly. When I check the SQL server network configuration > TCP/IP> properties, i see 10+ IP addresses active, but the only ones with ports is the assigned IP and the IPAll. Can you help me determine if there is a problem with the set up that causes hostname access to slow down?

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: we are using windows OS

Comment: Make sure that you can use ping `mysqlservername.example.com` and `mysqlservername` from the clients and from the server you can find the hostname of the mysql client by reverse searching its name from the clients IP address with `nslookup 123.123.123.123`